# My CNN model predicts only the first class no matter what image I put

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am beginner in Machine Learning and followed a template in one of the ML courses to train images of Cats and Dogs to classify them.

If I load  an image to be predicted in my model, no matter what, the prediction comes to be the first class I have defined in the list platetype at the end.

I am doing this to classify other type of images however I was getting the same error to that dataset so I thought of using the classic cats and dogs dataset.

I want to predict that if the image of text I give to the trained model has a fancy text or a standard text font.

Here is my code.

```
#create classifier 
classifier = Sequential()

#adding convolution layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))


# In[54]:

#compiling
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# In[55]:
#making Image size same
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'D:/Third Year/kaggle/cats/New Data/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'D:/Third Year/kaggle/cats/New Data/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
print('TRAINING:',training_set)
print('TEST: ',test_set)


# In[56]:

#checking if already a weight file exists. if it does loads it into the model
if os.path.isfile("modelCNN_CD.h5") :
        classifier.load_weights("modelCNN_CD.h5")

#checkpoint saves the model.
filepath="modelCNN_CD.h5"       
checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')


classifier.summary()
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=2000,callbacks=[checkpoint1,])


# In[67]:
# load the model
#model = VGG16()
# load an image from file
image = load_img('D:/Third Year/kaggle/cats/New Data/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dog.4029.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))
# convert the image pixels to a numpy array
image = img_to_array(image)
# reshape data for the model
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))

yhat = classifier.predict(image)
print(yhat)

import numpy as np
print(platetype[np.argmax(yhat)])

# In[57]:

platetype = ['Cat','Dog']

# In[9]:

from keras.models import load_model
classifier = load_model('modelCNN_LP.h5')
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a more specific question. "Does not work" and a very long code listing make it difficult to help you. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sorry, but the thing is I am not sure which part of the code may be responsible for the problem being caused.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why you should create an MCVE. Quite often, when you try to create an MCVE, you will discover the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, keeping it in mind, I have tried reducing the code to the minimum in the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Is your predictor always returning 0 as the class?

The reason why I ask is that I was having the same problem and the issue is with `"platetype[np.argmax(yhat)]"` and the fact you are using binary class mode classification.

argmax would be returning the index position of the result but as you are using binary classes and in your final layer you have 1 dense. It will only return a single value so it will always return the first class (0 as the index position). As the network is only set, to return one class.

There are 2 solutions and it depends which you prefer:

1. Is to change the class_mode to 'categorical' for the train and test generators, change the final dense layer from 1 to 2 so this will return scores/probabilities for both classes. So when you use argmax, it will return the index position of the top score indicating which class it has predicted.
2. The other way would be to stick with what you have got but you would have to change how to determine the class. You would use the score so yhat will be a list. You would need to access the score and based on that determine which class the model has predicted. Maybe someone can clarify this as I have not use this method and I am not sure.

Hope this helps!. I had the same issue as you and this fixed it for me (I went with option 1).

Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reason why your model is unable to make an accurate prediction of your new image is because you forgot to rescale it.

You used ImageDataGenerator() during training with a rescaling factor of 1./255.

Just add :

```
...
image = load_img('D:/Third Year/kaggle/cats/New Data/Convolutional_Neural_Networks/dog.4029.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))

image = img_to_array(image)

image = image/255.  # Add this line 

image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))

yhat = classifier.predict(image)
...
```

and it should work.